# How to update an add-in field code without losing field data (MS Word)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an add-in field in MS Word which also has some hidden data. I want to update the field's code text. However, when I do so and read my hidden data again, they are gone. See this minimal example:

```
Sub testUpdatingFieldCode()
  Dim newField As Field
  Set newField = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldAddin)
  newField.Code.Text = " ADDIN mycode \* MERGEFORMAT "
  newField.Data = "mydata"

  Debug.Print "Code: " & newField.Code.Text
  Debug.Print "Data: " & newField.Data ' works - prints "Data: mydata"

  newField.Code.Text = " ADDIN mycodechanged \* MERGEFORMAT "
  Debug.Print "Code: " & newField.Code.Text
  Debug.Print "Data: " & newField.Data ' doesn't work - prints "Data: "
End Sub
```

Is this normal behaviour or a bug? Is there a suggested way to update field codes without losing the data?

I could save the `Data` to a variable like this but I'm worried about performance (I ultimately need to do this for tens or hundreds fields at a time):

```
Dim previousData As String: previousData = newField.Data
newField.Code.Text = " ADDIN my_code_changed  \* MERGEFORMAT "
newField.Data = previousData
```

Comment: You should be able to create hundreds of variables without a problem. You should also look into using Document Variables as a possible data storage solution. https://wordribbon.tips.net/T011561_Understanding_Document_Variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying your code, it **does** insert the field and does change the value.

[image: Field code { ADDIN mycodechanged * MERGEFORMAT }]

The problem seems to be with **.Data** because the field is there in the document.

I join John Korchok's suggestion that you use Document variables instead. They can hold text information and it is not normally accessible to the user. It is not in the text of the document and so not subject to accidental deletion by the user. You can have multiple variables in a document. They can be displayed in the document if you want through a DocVariable field which is a reporting, not an editing, field.

Here is a [link to the support document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables) on document variables. Two code examples from that page:

```
ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="Value1", Value:="1" 
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Variables("Value1") + 3

For Each myVar In ActiveDocument.Variables 
 MsgBox "Name =" & myVar.Name & vbCr & "Value = " & myVar.Value 
Next myVar
```

As you can see, this is a much simpler construction than using the AddIn Field. There are several utilities available that give access to document variables from within the User Interface but nothing in Word out of the box that allows the user to change variables without vba.

*[EDIT to address concerns in first comment.]*

### You can use the Feedback mechanism in Word to complain about the problem with the Addin field. I do not know that it will be fixed because there are such better tools available. More likely is that they will delete or deprecate the field. I know of no way to work around this and get the result you want. Even deleting the field and recreating it does not allow you to get the data.

You can use Document Properties as well as Document Variables. Those are available to the user through the Advanced Properties. In addition, certain properties are available through the Quick Parts menu where a change in the property content control in the document changes the property itself. These are mapped to XML nodes. Like Document Variables, all Document Properties can be displayed through a (reporting) field: DocProperty. My [page on Repeating Data](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm) shows some uses that can be made using these built-in mapped Document Property Content Controls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, document variables seem to be a good alternative. However, I'm working on a bigger project and changing the overall approach is not an option at this point.
Also, I think the field `Data` even makes sense in our case because the data should be connected with the field, when the user deletes the field, it is actually correct the data are dropped, too. So there would have to be a way of syncing the fields with the document variables.

Comment: You want the user to be able to delete the data? You want them to be able to do this by accident because they do not see the field? That is how the Addin field works, to the extent it works.---- As far as I can tell, the Addin field is, itself, broken for your application ----- You could also use the Document Properties from the Quick Parts menu. Those allow the user to quickly and easily change them from within the document.

Comment: The users always see the add-in field's text (`field.Result.Text`), that text should be part of the final document, only `field.Data` is not visible. So they can't remove just the data by accident. If they decide to remove the whole field, that's completely fine and it's also desired the `.Data` are deleted, too. How would I remove data from the Document Properties when the user deletes a field?

Comment: Anyway, even if that was possible, I can't change the used approach at this point. So I guess the answer to the original question is that it is a bug and I should report it using the Feedback mechanism. My workaround with `previousData` works but it is still weird and unexpected.

Comment: Looks like we've gone as far as we can here. The user deleting a field or document property content control will not delete the document property or variable. It will just not be displayed in the document.